# Is it possible to make enzyme work with RN + hooks?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, enzyme, react-hooks

I've got a project what used to be a normal React project (before the hooks hype). My stack for testing included jest + enzyme.

Now want to move to hooks, but I can't make it work. For some reason my instance won't update on an a set callback.

Example:

Given then next component:

```
export type CounterReturnType = [number, () => void, () => void]

export function useCounter(): CounterReturnType {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => {
        console.log('PRESSED')
        setCount(count => count + 1)
    }
    const decrement = () => { setCount(count => count - 1) }
    return [count, increment, decrement]
}

export default function HooksTest() {
    const [count, increment, decrement] = useCounter();
    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.counter}>
                <Text style={style.counterText} testID='counter'>{count}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={style.actions}>
                <Touchable style={style.increment} onPress={increment} testID='increment'>
                    <Text>Increment</Text>
                </Touchable>
                <Touchable style={style.decrement} onPress={decrement} testID='decrease'>
                    <Text>Decrement</Text>
                </Touchable>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I made a simple test like the next:

```
it('increment to 1 on click', async () => {
        const component = shallow(<HooksTest />);
        const counter = component.findWhere(node => node.prop("testID") === "counter")
        const incrementButton = component.findWhere(node => node.prop("testID") === "increment")
        incrementButton.simulate('press')
        expect(counter.getElement().props.children).toEqual(1);
    })
```

But the counter do not want to update at all. Is there a way to make this work, or I should instead use another library?

Comment: some things may not work for `shallow` while other may be fixed but not released yet. see https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011 for reference. try using `mount`. if it works you may use it as a workaround.